# Bash: Need to compare two CSV lists of country codes, output just the country codes in the second file that don't appear in the first

Tags: bash, csv

I have two CSV files with a list of two letter country codes formatted like:

```
('AU','AT,'BE'...'VE')
```

No code appears twice in the same file.

I need to compare the two files, and export ONLY the country codes in the second file that do not appear in the first, to a third csv file in a similar format.

Alternatively, the lists aren't very long so I could paste the entire list into bash itself and just copy the output to a new csv file.

file 1: amp.csv

```
('AU','AT','BE','BO','CA','CL','CO','CR','CZ','DK','DO','EC','SV','FI','FR','DE','GR','GT','HN','HU','IE','IT','LI','LU','MX','NL','NZ','NI','NO','PA','PY','PE','PL','PT','RU','SK','ES','SE','CH','UA','GB','US','VE')
```

file 2: google.csv

```
('AR','AU','AT','BY','BE','BO','BA','BR','BG','CA','CL','CO','CR','HR','CY','CZ','DK','DO','EC','SV','EE','FI','FR','DE','GR','GT','HN','HU','IS','IE','IT','JP','LV','LI','LT','LU','MK','MT','MX','NL','NZ','NI','NO','PA','PY','PE','PL','PT','RO','RU','SK','SI','ES','SE','CH','UA','UK','US','UY','VE')
```

export to 3: diff.csv

```
('XX','YY',ZZ')
```

(where xx yy and zz are the country codes that appear in file 2 but not file 1)

I've tried several variations of grep commands I've found in other questions about comparing csv files, but they always seem to output everything in file 2 as everything is in one line.

such as `grep A.csv -f B.csv`

tried:

```
comm -13 <(sort amp.csv) <(sort google.csv)
```

and it just outputs the entire second file.

```
('AR','AU','AT','BY','BE','BO','BA','BR','BG','CA','CL','CO','CR','HR','CY','CZ','DK','DO','EC','SV','EE','FI','FR','DE','GR','GT','HN','HU','IS','IE','IT','JP','LV','LI','LT','LU','MK','MT','MX','NL','NZ','NI','NO','PA','PY','PE','PL','PT','RO','RU','SK','SI','ES','SE','CH','UA','UK','US','UY','VE')
```

tried:

```
diff amp.csv google.csv
```

and that seemed to just print each file similarly to:

```
1c1
< ('AU','AT','BE','BO','CA','CL','CO','CR','CZ','DK','DO','EC','SV','FI','FR','DE','GR','GT','HN','HU','IE','IT','LI','LU','MX','NL','NZ','NI','NO','PA','PY','PE','PL','PT','RU','SK','ES','SE','CH','UA','GB','US','VE')
\ No newline at end of file`
```

Comment: Please show some sample input file, together with its desired output and what you tried so far. Give a read to [ask] to get a better insight on how to ask properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input files are already sorted then this should work.

```
comm -13 <(tr -d '()' < file1 | tr , '\n' | sort) <(tr -d '()' < file2 | tr , '\n' | sort)
```

The first `tr` command deletes the `()` characters.
The second converts the commas to newlines.
Then we `sort` the, now line-delimited, data.
At which point `comm` can do its job properly (since we have sorted line-delimited data).

To convert that into your desired output format you can use this.

```
comm -13 ..... | tr '\n' , | sed 's/^/(/;s/,$/)/'
```

First we use `tr` to convert back from line-delimited to comma-delimited output.
Then we use sed to delete the trailing `,` and add the wrapping `()`.

Comment: they aren't sorted so I tried: `comm -13 <(tr -d '()' < amp.csv | tr | sort , '\n') <(tr -d '()' < google.csv | tr | sort, '\n')` and that resulted in `sort: open failed: ,: No such file or directory
-bash: sort,: command not found`

Comment: I didn't mean after the word `tr` literally. I meant after the second `tr` command. `... | tr , '\n' | sort`

Comment: You legend. Tried the edited version above and got the output I needed: `'AR'
'BA'
'BG'
'BR'
'BY'
'CY'
'EE'
'HR'
'IS'
'JP'
'LT'
'LV'
'MK'
'MT'
'RO'
'SI'
'UK'
'UY'`

Answer (score 0):

Look into the diff command. It's a good tool, and you can read all about it by typing in your terminal man diff.

The command you'll want to do is diff File_1.txt File_2.txt which will output the difference between the two and should look something like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Additionally you might notice the 4th command is diff ... | tee Output_File this outputs the results from tee into a file, so that you can save it for later if you don't want to view it all on the console right that second.

Comment: tried diff amp.csv google.csv (the two csv files) and it seemed to just print the contents of both files.

Comment: @John didn't see what was output in your reply

Comment: tried to paste the output in but even with indenting for the code block it seemed to trigger some HTML.

Comment: @John I searched for a well put explanation of diff online and this was the best: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm

Comment: I'm pretty sure at this point that the main problem is my format. It's all in one line of text, the codes aren't sorted alphanumerically, and most comparison commands seem to depend on the file having each thing to compare on a separate line.

Comment: A script option might be if [ file1 == file2 ]; then echo "SAME" else echo "DIFFERENT" fi

Comment: You can then save it as .sh and make it executable by using chmod u+x scriptname

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
sed -e 's/,/\n/g' -e "s/['\(\)]//g" file
```

on the input files to get a country code on each line, and then use `comm` to find the lines that exist only in the second file.

Comment: tried: `sed -e 's/,/\n/g' -e 's/["\(\)]//g' amp.csv` and got this
`'AU'n'AT'n'BE'n'BO'n'CA'n'CL'n'CO'n'CR'n'CZ'n'DK'n'DO'n'EC'n'SV'n'FI'n'FR'n'DE'n'GR'n'GT'n'HN'n'HU'n'IE'n'IT'n'LI'n'LU'n'MX'n'NL'n'NZ'n'NI'n'NO'n'PA'n'PY'n'PE'n'PL'n'PT'n'RU'n'SK'n'ES'n'SE'n'CH'n'UA'n'GB'n'US'n'VE'`

Comment: I adjusted the quotes, see above. Still don't know why the \n is not accepted. What OS are you on?

Comment: Tried again after you adjusted the quotes: `AUnATnBEnBOnCAnCLnCOnCRnCZnDKnDOnECnSVnFInFRnDEnGRnGTnHNnHUnIEnITnLInLUnMXnNLnNZnNInNOnPAnPYnPEnPLnPTnRUnSKnESnSEnCHnUAnGBnUSnVE`